# jquery smooth scroll to an anchor in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, scroll

I'm trying to implement jquery smooth scroll to an anchor after clicking the menu item in the wordpress. I'm using this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/

Here is the js file:

```
 $(".anchor_scroll").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 //calculate destination place
 var dest=0;
 if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
    dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
}else{
    dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
}
//go to destination
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 5000,'swing');
});
```

In my wordpress page I create a section:

```
<section id="services"></section>
```

and in the wordpress custom menu put a class "anchor_scroll" to a link:

```
<a class="anchor_scroll" href="#services">.
```

After this I'm able to navigate to an anchor in the page after pressing the link, however, the jquery code seems to be not working, because there is no smooth slide effect, just jump.

Comment: any errors in the console? how are you adding your script to wordpress?

Comment: Try this `$('#services').on('click', ".scroll", function (event) {`

Comment: @Tushar I don't see how this could be of any help, specially with this selector (you target the destination, not the link).

Comment: I register my script in functions.php file of my theme:  `wp_enqueue_script( 'anchor-slide', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/anchor_slide.js', array());` I can see in the source code of my site, that the .js file is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I would use for this;

```
$(".anchor_scroll").click(function(){
    var section = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(section).offset().top - 15
    });  
});
```